# Confusion regarding a supertask problem in elementary probability

Tags: combinatorics, infinity

The subject is example 6a from chapter 2 of "*A First Course in Probability*" by Sheldon Ross (9th edition):

> Suppose that we possess an infinitely large urn and an infinite collection of balls labeled ball number 1, number 2, number 3, and so on. Consider an experiment performed as follows: At 1 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 1 through 10 are placed in the urn and ball number 10 is withdrawn. (Assume that the withdrawal takes no time.) At 1/2 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 11 through 20 are placed in the urn and ball number 20 is withdrawn. At 1/4 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 21 through 30 are placed in the urn and ball number 30 is withdrawn. At 1/8 minute to 12 P.M., and so on. The question of interest is, How many balls are in the urn at 12 P.M.?

> The answer to this question is clearly that there is an infinite number of balls in the urn at 12 P.M., since any ball whose number is not of the form 10n, n >= 1, will have been placed in the urn and will not have been withdrawn before 12 P.M. Hence, the problem is solved when the experiment is performed as described.

> However, let us now change the experiment and suppose that at 1 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 1 through 10 are placed in the urn and ball number 1 is withdrawn; at 1/2 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 11 through 20 are placed in the urn and ball number 2 is withdrawn; at 1/4 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 21 through 30 are placed in the urn and ball number 3 is withdrawn; at 1/8 minute to 12 P.M., balls numbered 31 through 40 are placed in the urn and ball number 4 is withdrawn, and so on. For this new experiment, how many balls are in the urn at 12 P.M.?

> Surprisingly enough, the answer now is that the urn is empty at 12 P.M. For, consider any ball—say, ball number n. At some time prior to 12 P.M. [in particular, at (1/2)^(n-1) minutes to 12 P.M.], this ball would have been withdrawn from the urn. Hence, for each n, ball number n is not in the urn at 12 P.M.; therefore, the urn must be empty at that time.

My objection is as follows: How do the cases differ? All I see is that we are changing the order in which the balls are removed, not the quantity of balls removed in each time instant.

For every time instant, let us create a tuple of $(ball\  removed,balls\ added)$. Over the entire super task, the collection of our tuples will be:

$\left\{
(1,\left\{1,2,...10  \right\}),(2,\left\{11,12,...20  \right\}),(3,\left\{21,22,...30  \right\})\ ...  \right\}$

Now, the nth ball is removed at $(1/2)^{n-1}$ minutes to 12 PM. At the same instant, the set of balls $\left\{10n-1,...,10n  \right\}$ are added. Thus, for every time instant where a ball is removed, we are also adding a greater number of balls to the urn.

Ultimately, the number of resultant balls at $(1/2)^{n-1}$ minutes to 12 PM $= \ 9n$.

I can't seem to understand the reasoning put forth by the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that the number of balls after $n$ steps is $9n$ in either method. The question is about what happens as you take the limit $n\to\infty$, and as is often the case, infinities are weird.

In the first method, $\frac{9}{10}$ of the balls are put in, and stay in; the set of balls $k$ which are still in at $n=\infty$ is $\{k \in \mathbb N : 10 \not \mid k\}$. In the second method, every ball is inserted, and then later removed; the set of balls still in at $n=\infty$ is empty.

This may seem strange; if we have $9n$ balls after $n$ steps, shouldn't we have $\infty$ balls after $\infty$ steps? Well, sort of. The limit of the number of balls is $\infty$, yes, but the limit of the set of balls is empty. These limits don't match, because infinity is weird.

Comment: Ultimately, will the urn be empty at 12 PM?

Comment: You have to define your terms. Is the limit of the number of balls zero? No. Is the limit of the set of balls empty? Yes. Which of those answers your question? Depends how you interpret the problem. @AlanWhitteaker

Comment: (In a probability book, you might use this example as motivation for the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem); it shows you can have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int f_n d\mu \ne \int \lim_{n\to\infty}f_n d\mu$.)

Answer (score 3):

The urn will be empty if and only if given $n\in \mathbb N $, the $n$th ball is not in the urn. In the first case, ball $1$ is still in the urn. But in the second case, you can actually explicitly compute when that ball will be removed from the case. So if the case is not empty, then you can find some ball in it. But you can't because tell me any candidate, and I can tell you when I took it out.

Comment: This thought experiment is basically the notion of cardinality and bijections, though with a probabilistic twist. Look into set cardinality and countable infinities if you want to think some more about this.

Comment: If I tell you any candidate then you can tell me when it was removed, sure (call this collection of balls removed as set A). My issue is that I can also provide you the set of balls that were added simultaneously (set B). Now, |A|<|B| and the inequality can be shown to be maintained via induction. So how does the answer accommodate for this? 
Since you have mentioned bijections, isn't our function here from N -> N non-injective?

Comment: Induction doesn't hold when dealing with infinity. For example, $1/n>0$ for every $n$. But $\lim_n 1/n = 0$. Or putting $a_n = $ first $n$ digits of $\sqrt 2$, you get $a_n \in \mathbb Q$ for every $n$. But $a_{\infty} = \sqrt 2$. The point here is that given countable sets $A_1,\dots,A_{10}$, I can biject $\mathbb N$ with $\bigcup_{i\in [10]} A_i$.

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [Ross-Littlewood Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ross%E2%80%93Littlewood_paradox).

And yeah, it's called a paradox not for nothing.

In fact, I personally think it's an excellent argument against the very idea of completing supertasks.

Comment: I don't think it's an argument against supertasks in the broad sense implied by your statement. The set H1 of all ⟨P,X⟩ such that P is a program that halts on input X is well-defined, even if we cannot constructed it in reality. It is also the limit of a 'supertask' that simply runs all pairs and adds halting ones to the set. Once you accept this, consider the set H2 of all ⟨P,X⟩ such that P is a program that can use H1 as an oracle function and halts on input X. Accepting that H1 is well-defined forces you to accept that H2 is well-defined too. But H2 is the limit of a 'supertask' too.

Comment: Each ⟨P,X⟩∈H2 is witnessed by a finite trace T of P with finitely many calls C[1..n] to H1, where each C[k] is witnessed by some ⟨Q[k],Y[k]⟩ such that Q[k] halts on Y[k] iff T asserts so. Phase 1: Search through all traces of normal programs on all inputs, to figure out the answers to all queries to H1. Phase 2: Search through all possible such traces T, and if you find one asserting that P halts on X that agrees with the information from Phase 1, then you add ⟨P,X⟩ to the set.

Comment: Just because we cannot do it in reality doesn't imply anything about whether it is well-defined, and the 'supertask' in this thread is certainly way more obviously well-defined than H2. But you can't claim that H2 is ill-defined unless you also claim that H1 is ill-defined! Doing so would also force you to reject classical PA. In fact, you cannot accept much more than 3-valued/intuitionistic PA⁻. That is really really weak.

Comment: @user21820 All agreed!  But I think that often the source of the confusion regarding these kinds of supertasks *is* the idea that we can finish them. Sure, there is a well-defined mathematical notion of limit here, but when you ask 'how many balls are there at noon?' we really can't answer that, because 1) we are only told what happens before noon, and 2) we can't even get to noon if that requires us actually completing a supertask.

Comment: Ah so that's what you meant. Indeed! I misinterpreted because usually the people talking about "supertasks" are saying something different, either that supertasks exist in reality (which we reject), or that all supertasks are ill-defined (which we reject too). Anyway, to expand on your point for future readers, it is that until we define what the state is at noon, it is actually ill-defined to ask for the state at noon! Ross failed to define the state at noon. He cannot claim to be relying on the common assumption of continuity, since the process is obviously not continuous.

Comment: @user21820 Thanks!  I'll readily admit that my 'answer' was really more of a quick comment and not well developed.